# Subscription inside the error function handling from outer subscription

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a case of subscription inside another subscription and we know that's bad. The problem is I don't know how to solve it here:

```js
this.backendService.doSomething().subscribe(
  () => { },
  err => {
    this.someService.showOkMessage('title', 'you got an error')
      .subscribe(); // The bad guy
  },
  () => {
    // should not be called if there is an error
    this.someService.showOkMessage('title', 'everything is fine')
      .subscribe(); // Another bad guy
  }
}
```

I tried something like this:

```js
this.backendService.doSomething().pipe(
  catchError(errMsg => {
    return someService.showOkMessage('title', 'you got an error').map(() => true));
  )},
  switchMap(isError =>
    if(!isError) return someService.showOkMessage('title', 'everything is fine');
  )
).subscribe();
```

This works but dosn't feel right, I don't want to transform/change the stream, it should just end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to a bit of reordering, when there is an error it'll skip to `catchError()`
if not erroring it'll run `switchMap`

```
this.backendService.doSomething().pipe(
  switchMap(()=> someService.showOkMessage('title', 'everything is fine')),
  catchError(errMsg => 
    someService.showOkMessage('title', 'you got an error')
  ),
).subscribe();
```

Comment: Oh, somewhat thought it would still go through the switchMap, even with the error... 
This works, thank you!